# With an older version of PgAdmin, when creating a database, we cannot find where to set IS_TEMPLATE

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

We are using PgAdmin connecting to an instance of PostgreSQL.

With PgAdmin, in the context of `Servers > [the_server_login] > Databases > Create > Database`, we input the necessary parameters, hopping to let the wizard generate the following sample SQL from a document.

```sql
CREATE DATABASE "Metabase_VM"
    WITH
    OWNER = metabase
    ENCODING = 'UTF8'
    LC_COLLATE = 'en_US.UTF-8'
    LC_CTYPE = 'en_US.UTF-8'
    TABLESPACE = pg_default
    CONNECTION LIMIT = -1
    IS_TEMPLATE = False;
```

However, so far, we only get the following generated SQL:

```sql
CREATE DATABASE "Metabase_VM"
    WITH 
    OWNER = metabase
    ENCODING = 'UTF8'
    LC_COLLATE = 'en_US.UTF-8'
    LC_CTYPE = 'en_US.UTF-8'
    TABLESPACE = pg_default
    CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;
```

**Our Questions:**

The current generated SQL is missing `IS_TEMPLATE = False`, so where on the GUI can we set this parameter?

We are new to PostgreSQL and PgAdmin, so we highly appreciate any hints and suggestions.

Comment: which version are you using pgaddmin 4 has no problem with it, maybe you should update to the last Subversion

Comment: I checked the `Help`, and it says pgAdmin 4, version `6.4`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FALSE` is the default value for `IS_TEMPLATE`, so there is nothing you have to do. See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createdatabase.html#CREATE-DATABASE-ISTEMPLATE):

> `istemplate`
>
> If true, then this database can be cloned by any user with `CREATEDB` privileges; if false (the default), then only superusers or the owner of the database can clone it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @laurenz-albe, and yes, `IS_TEMPLATE` is `FALSE` by default.

Also, credits should also go to @nbk for reminding me to upgrade the version of `pgAdmin`. So, after upgrading from `v6.4` to the current latest version `v8.4`, the option `Template?` appeared in the tab `Definition` of the Create Database wizard.

We have clearly resolved our questions now.

Comment: Hi Mike, the answer section is for answers only. You show thanks by upvoting and you flag the correct answer by ticking it